# Why am I winning (and losing) low league points, even if I'm not even close to promotion?

Tags: league-of-legends

So before the unfortunate day happened (internet fall down, got afk one whole ranked game) I was getting 15-26 LP for each win/lose. But after that day, I'm winning/losing only between 3-7 lp.

I'm **Bronze I** with around always 50-60LP, I had a winning streak and a losing streak.

Actually, also my question is: shouldn't a winning streak raise my lp winnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you shouldn't just get more LP after a winstreak.

Say you have a certain MMR (Matchmaking Rating). After the winstreak, you play versus better opponents. But your MMR is lower than theirs. Therefore, you have to 'proof' your skill to the system and continue to win. After a winstreak, your MMR can be a little higher. You'll play against slightly better opponents, but not the ones you've ended your winstreak with. This will make sure your LP winnings (and thus your ranking) is according to your MMR.

You may not have won more LP, but you've definately gained some MMR. This means that if you end up against the exact same opponents you've started your winstreak with, you'll gain more LP after winning from them, because your MMR would say you are better than them and thus deserve to gain more LP.

You've also stated you are Bronze I. That is an exceptional class (all I's), where you have to prove you are really ready to move up a division (which is, in terms of regular play, 'permanent'). You cannot downgrade to Bronze (unless you don't play for a long time) so you have to prove you are up for silver (and thus raise your MMR accordingly).

TL:DR: The harder your enemies get, if you defeat them, the less LP you get but the more your MMR rises. The harder your enemies get, if you lose against them, the less LP you lose and the less your MMR goes down.

The easier your enemies get, if you defeat them, the more LP you get and the less MMR you rise (so you will be even 'better' then your enemies). The easier your enemies get, if you lose against them, the more LP you lose and the more your MMR goes down.

The point where the definition of your enemy goes from 'he is easier' to 'he is harder' is your current MMR.

Comment: But won't that happen only when you're closer to promotion? Because before anything, I was winning between 15-26 LP, as I stated.

Comment: Then perhaps you reached your MMR treshhold. Do note that if you haven't played a lot of games (200-500+), the system has to calibrate itself which can lead to increase/decrease MMR at a fast rate. Perhaps if you lose 1 or 2 games, you'll gain 15-26 LP for a win again.

Comment: So in short, you don't only need to prove that you are capable of heading into silver, but at the time you reach your MMR-border, you'll have to (continually) prove you are better then your current MMR.

Comment: @Fabián I've made an edit to my post, read that. I might be incorrect (to anyone, please correct me if I'm wrong) but I believe that's the way it works.

Comment: The only I know from all 1's divisions is that you win less lp and you lose less lp than normal.
Like @Joetjah Said, it's because you have to play a lot to prove you can go to next division!

Comment: The amount of MMR to get into the next divison and the amount of MMR you have is probably lower. Therefore you gain less LP, so MMR has time to catch up untill your MMR is silver level.

Comment: If I reach Silver V, then the system will give me even more less lp? or more than (at least) the first division of the previous tier?

Comment: @Fabián When you promote to the next division, you are likely to gain some more LP then in the first tier of a lower division. You've proven yourself to be in Silver V thus your MMR is at silver standards. You can expect some more LP than before, but not too much though.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought. Thanks for the explanation mate!